# Iterating and instantiating game objects via a list

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have a list full of game objects I'm trying to iterate through and spawn one at a time. When a new game object spawns, I'm wanting the old one to disappear. However, at the moment my code is spawning my entire gameobject list as opposed to just the one element.

Can someone please take a look over my code to see what I'm doing wrong?

```
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10,130,100,50), "Forward"))
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < object_List.Count; i++)
        {
            Instantiate((GameObject)object_List[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're looping over the entire array so you would instantiate `n` objects (Where `n` is the size of the array).

Comment: I'd say that you need to read up on some C# basics if you can't figure this one out. You are using a for-loop to go through your whole object_list and then creating all of the objects, there isn't anything in there that even hints at creating them one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to instance an object every time you press the button, while at the same time deleting the currently spawned object.
Create a private scoped variable to store your current index:

```
private int index = 0;
```

Then you can go ahead and instance on object at a time:

```
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10,130,100,50), "Forward"))
{
    if (index > 0 && object_List[index] != null)
    {
        Destroy((GameObject)object_List[index]);
    }
    Instantiate((GameObject)object_List[index]);
    index ++;
}
```

You just need to do some checking whether index is actually larger than your list, so you won't get an IndexOutOfBounds Exception.

Comment: No problem, remember to mark upvote / mark answers as correct if you are satisfied with them :)